# C# WinForms ComboBox SelectedValueChanged event firing delayed

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

Update:

I did not find the true reason yet but I found out, that updating a property of any other databound control raises the 'delayed' event from the Folder-Combobox.
By far not a clean solution, but I helped myself by updating a unsued property. That is, until I learn about the true reason.

---

Original Post:

I am currently working on a Windows.Forms project (has to be WinForms unfortunately) and there I have three ComboBoxes whichs DataSources are bound to a List each. The lists contain folder or file names.
Also the SelectedItem Property of each Combobox is bound to a string.
The SelectedValueChanged event is registered and implemented.

They depend on each other, so when I update the DataSource of combobox1, the DataSource of combobox2 has to be updated, too. This is because in combobox1 you can select a subdirectory for files which are then listed in combobox2.

Now here is the problem. Sometimes it happens, that when I update the SelectedItem in combobox1 programmatically, the SelectedValueChanged event is not fireing right away. The program continues, until the DataSource of combobox2 is updated. THEN only, the SelectedValueChanged event method of combobox1 is executed but unfortunately it is "too late" as the DataSource of combobox2 is already updated with a wrong subdirectory from combobox1.

I would like to understand, which the event is not fired right away. Below I have posted an abbreviated example of the relevant code section.

```
// Cmb1Data and Cmb2Data are the String-Lists which are bound to the DataSource property of the ComboBoxes
// TempCmb1(2)SelectedValue is a string value which contains the value which is to be set.
// Cmb1(2)SelectedValue is a string which is bound the the SelectedItem property of the ComboBoxes

List<string> TempCmb1Data = MainVM.GetCmb1Data();
// some if-statement (plausibility check) is done here before the DataSource is updated.
Cmb1Data = TempCmb1Data ;
if (Cmb1Data.Contains(TempCmb1SelectedValue)
    Cmb1SelectedValue = TempCmb1SelectedValue; // This should fire the event - but sometimes it does not...

List<string> TempCmb2Data = MainVM.GetCmb2Data();
// as before, some if-statement (plausibility check) is done here before the DataSource is updated.
Cmb2Data = TempCmb2Data; // This is the point, where the SelectedValueChangedEvent of Combobox1 suddenly is fired, followed by the SelectdValueChanged event of Combobox 2
```

I have double checked all data bindings and event method registrations, they are all OK. Also everything runs fine, if I change the SelectedItem manually - just sometimes it has to be done programatically.

Thank you in advance.
Aar

---

Edit:

So I summarized the code to the relevant sections (as posted below). When I tested this code to make sure it is correct, the problem did not occur. It appears to me, that the problem is hidden somewhere else and without knowing where, it is just too much code to post here. I will take a deep look again and post an update if I found the problem.

```
public partial class Form
{
    RuntimeData _RuntimeData = new RuntimeData();

    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddDataBindings();
    }
    
    private void AddDataBindings()
    {
        cmbFolders.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", _RuntimeData , "SelectedFolder");
        cmbFolders.DataBindings.Add("DataSource",   _RuntimeData , "Folders");
        cmbFiles.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem",   _RuntimeData , "SelectedFile");
        cmbFiles.DataBindings.Add("DataSource",     _RuntimeData , "Files");
    }

    bool _ToggleFlag = false;
    private void btTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string TcpString = "Cmd=Execute;Dir=SubDirName1;File=FileName1.dat;";

         if (_ToggleFlag)
             TcpString = "Cmd=Execute;Dir=SubDirName2;File=FileName2.dat;";

         _ToggleFlag = !_ToggleFlag;

         // Method is usually executed in separate thread but the problem exists either way. So Threading removed for simplification
         ParseAndExecute(TcpString, _RuntimeData);
    }

    private void ParseAndExecute(string tcpString, RuntimeData runtimeData)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tcpString))
            return;

        string[] Elements = tcpString.Split(new char[] { ';', '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Replaced GetFolders-Method for simplification
        List<string> TempFolders = new List<string>() { "SubDirName1", "SubDirName2", "SubDirName3" };
        if (TempFolders [0] == Elements[3])
            ;//runtimeData.ProcessFolderChange = true;
        runtimeData.Folders.Clear();
        runtimeData.Folders = TempFolders;
        if (runtimeData.Folders.Contains(Elements[3]))
        {
             if (runtimeData.Folders[0] != Elements[3])
                 ;//runtimeData.ProcessFolderChange = true;
             runtimeData.SelectedFolder = Elements[3];
        }

        // Replaced GetFiles-Method for simplification
        List<string> TempFiles = new List<string>() { "FileName1.dat", "FileName2.dat", "FileName3.dat" };
        if (TempFiles [0] == Elements[5])
            ;//runtimeData.ProcessFileChange = true;
        runtimeData.Files.Clear();
        runtimeData.Files = TempFiles;
        if (runtimeData.Files.Contains(Elements[5]))
        {
             if (runtimeData.Files[0] != Elements[5])
                 ;//runtimeData.ProcessFileChange = true;
             runtimeData.SelectedFile = Elements[5];
        }
    }

    private void cmbFolders_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (!_RuntimeData.ProcessFolderChange)
            //return;
        //_RuntimeData.ProcessFolderChange = false;

        ((ComboBox)sender).DataBindings["SelectedItem"].WriteValue();

        _RuntimeData.Files.Clear();
        _RuntimeData.Files = new List<string>() { "FileName1.dat", "FileName2.dat", "FileName3.dat" };
    }

    private void cmbFiles_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (!_RuntimeData.ProcessFileChange)
            //return;
        //_RuntimeData.ProcessFileChange= false;

        ((ComboBox)sender).DataBindings["SelectedItem"].WriteValue();

        // do some random stuff with the file...
    }
}


// Relevant data from RuntimeData class.
public class RuntimeData : VMBase
{
    private List<string> folders = new List<string>() { "SubDirName1", "SubDirName2", "SubDirName3" };
    public List<string> Folders
    {
        get { return folders; }
        set
        {
            folders = value;            
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Folders"));
        }
    }
    
    private List<string> files = new List<string>()  { "FileName1.dat", "FileName2.dat", "FileName3.dat" };
    public List<string> Files
    {
        get { return files; }
        set
        {
            files = value;            
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Files"));
        }
    }

    string selectedFolder = String.Empty;
    public string SelectedFolder
    {
        get { return selectedFolder ; }
        set
        {
            selectedFolder = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedFolder"));
        }
    }

    string selectedFile = String.Empty;
    public string SelectedFile 
    {
        get { return selectedFile ; }
        set
        {
            selectedFile = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedFile"));
        }
    }
}

public abstract class VMBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectionChangeCommitted` (if you want a change event only when an Item is selected *manually*)?

Comment: I also want it to be changed, when e.g. an tcp-stream sends the data to be selected to my program. then the GUI is inactive and the values are changed programatically. I experienced problems with both events, SelectedIndexChanged and SelectionChangeCommitted.

Comment: It doesn't matter from where you receive a value used to set a Control (whatever that is). You can set the `SelectedValue` (or the `SelectedItem`, depending on what you get) of a ComboBox, after that, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is raised. Of course, your ComboBox must have its `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` defined correctly.

Comment: Just tried it using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Exactely the same behaviour: The event of combobox1 sometimes is only raised, when the datasource of combobox2 is updated. Oh, and it is raised _after_ the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of combobox2...

Comment: Post your code. Include how you set the DataSource, the code related to the event handlers of all ComboBox controls involved and how/when you trigger the `SelectedIndexChanged` of the first ComboBox. Note that, if you have some synchronization problem, you should try to `BeginInvoke()` the code you have in the first ComboBox, to let the event handler return before the changes (to other Controls) are applied.

Comment: Added code - which works perfectly fine (see edit comment). Thank you very much so far.

Comment: Looks like that's a huge amount of code that can be thrown away if you create a DataSet with 3 tables, relationships between them and then bind your combos to the relationships rather than the data. As an aside did you consider that a tree view might be a better ui tool for showing this hierarchy?

Comment: TreeView might be a better way for showing - but in my case the user has to make a manual selection via the comboboxes - or, as shown in the example, via a tcp-or-whatever-input. After the manual selection, the user has to start the actual execution of some program logic.
The DataSet is an idea which I will look into though. I have not worked with that so far, so I did not see that as a possible solution. Thanks for this advice!

Comment: So it turned out that I need to update ANY databound property of ANY other control to raise the `cmbFolders_SelectedValueChanged` event after setting the variable bound to `SelectedItem` of that Combobox. I am sure there is a reason for that but this is too high for me...

Comment: I'm thinking out loud here. Is it possible that when you reset the DataSource on ComboBox1, the actual `SelectedValue` doesn't change because it happens to be the same value as the first item in the new DataSource? I would try to force Combo2 and Combo3 to refresh their DataSource from where you reset the Combo1 DataSource. I hope you understand my gibberish.